# Contour triangulation

Tags: triangulation

I write my study and is stuck when i try triangulate the contour of surface. When it is in 2D its ok. When it in 3D a have trouble with triangle angle detection, i tried with:

Triange have 3 Vertices v1,v2,v3
I create 2 vectors(vec21, vec23) from v2v1 and v2v3
then vec21 x vec23 and obtain a det of matrix
on the stand which I define Span angle
I also check if edges do not crossing and if any point isnt in area of triangle.

But when it in 3D i choose point around polygon then this metod didn't work

Points of contour i want triangulate to flat polygon: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bw5-VXnqutXBckRJMGNJMW9JaXc

Bad resoult: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bw5-VXnqutXBMzV5elIxX1FaeDQ

In 2d:

Points on 2D :https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bw5-VXnqutXBWVE4bWJsZ09mOVk

Good resoults:https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bw5-VXnqutXBdGFKM2Z4UnFRdXc

Where i made mistake? Can u explain me this?

Greetings!

PS. Im interested in algoithm at 2 last case:http://www.cosy.sbg.ac.at/~held/projects/triang/triang.html

Answer (score 0):

Typically one would use a Delaunay Triangulation for the 2D case. For the 3D case you can project the points to 2D, triangulate and project the triangles back to 3D. This will of course only work if the patch to be triangulated can be projected to 2D (without selfintersections).