# Triangulate a polygon whose contour touches itself with poly2tri?

Tags: polygon, triangulation

[image]

Is it possible to triangulate a polygon which touches itself (like in the image above) with poly2tri?

Comment: Can this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582862/contour-triangulation?rq=1

Comment: My solution: use [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) to offset the polygon, triangulate it, and re-offset to obtain the final mesh.

Comment: I think you should use the 'answer you own question' option and post it. Could be useful for someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution: use Clipper to offset the polygon, triangulate it, and re-offset to obtain the final mesh.

Of course, this is a hack which does not always work since offsetting the polygon is a possibly destructive operation (if the are tiny ends on the polygon, they might not offset back to their original positions).